# How to use custom date picker to filter data in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

We have a custom date picker component in our application developed in  javascript , I want to use this component to filter column values in jqgrid (i.e. I want it to replace

`dataInit : function (elem) {
 $(elem).datepicker();
}`

How can I do that given that the custom component is like this :

`<IMG style="CURSOR: hand" onclick='datePick("field_to_fill_with_date_picked", this,"form_name")' border=0 src="/path/to/calendar/image.gif">`

Another question :  the previous code is actually not able to filter the data in the column .. it looks like below ... when I choose a date that is present in the column values nothing happens at all.

[image]

Comment: You should provide **the demo**, which can be used to reproduce the problem. Additionally you should always include the information about **the version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). It's very important to know `datatype` of the grid, the options of `formatter: "date"` and the format of input data in the date column. Demo (in jsfiddle) for example simplify all.

Comment: Try the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/zs013rbb/, which uses datepicker with free jqGrid 4.14.1.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get this picture's result?
[use bootstrap-datetimepicker.js resutl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEje7.png)

I did this use code :

```
{name:'CREATE_DATE_TIME',label:'创建时间',sortable:true,align:'center',
                    searchoptions : {
                        dataInit: function (element) {
                               $(element).datetimepicker({
                                    minView: 0, 
                                    language:  'zh-CN',
                                    format: "yyyy-mm-dd" ,
                                    todayBtn:  1,
                                    autoclose: 1
                                }); 
                          },
                    }
```

you can use your date plugin in dataInit callback function。

Answer (score 0):

In all cases in order to get answer of your problem you will need to provide more information about this datepicker component - I mean detailed description of parameters, can this component be used with jquery bind function and etc.

By example you say

```
datePick("field_to_fill_with_date_picked", this,"form_name")
```

What mean field_to_fill_with_date_picked - is this id or the name in the form.

You may want to look at [Guriddo jqGrid Knowledge Base](http://guriddo.net/?kbe_knowledgebase=jquery-ui-datepicker-search-on-select) and get idea how to trigger a search when selecting a date (using jQuery UI datepicker)