# Many issues with date filtering & formatting in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have one column in jqgrid that should handle date info, I have many issues with this column actually :

1- Date is returned from back-end and is displayed as follows `29/03/2017 00:00:00` ... so when I try to use a formatter like this : `formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y" }`, the date gets corrupted and and entirely different date is displayed instead `09-Aug-2033`

2- when I try to add a datepicker search, It does nothing, I mean no filtering happens at all and the grid data remains the same, regargless I use the above formatter or not

Actually I am relying on Oleg's example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/zs013rbb/)

my code after some modification :

```
{
  name: 'F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE',
  index: 'F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE',
  align: 'left',
  width: 100,
  sortable: true,
  search: true,
  editable: false,
  cellEdit: false,
  formatter: "date",
  formatoptions: {
    newformat: "d-M-Y"
  },
  editoptions: {
    dataInit: function(elem) {
      $(elem).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date",
        autoSize: true,
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        showWeek: true,
        onSelect: (function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            this.triggerToolbar();
          }, 0);
        })
      });
    }
  },
  searchoptions: {
    sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"],
    attr: {
      placeholder: "dd-M-yyyy"
    },
    dataInit: function(elem) {
      $(elem).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date",
        autoSize: true,
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        showWeek: true,
        onSelect: (function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            this.triggerToolbar();
          }, 0);
        })
      });
    }
  }
}
```

jquery version : 1.9.1

jqGrid version : 4.5.0

Concerning fork, I am not sure, It's actually part of the liferay libraries, but seems to be the free version.

This is related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44997340/how-to-use-custom-date-picker-to-filter-data-in-jqgrid), but with more details and different requirements

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify the source format of the incomming date - the default is ISO data like Y-m-d. So this to work you will need to set srcformat options like this:

```
  {
  name: 'F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE',
  index: 'F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE',
  align: 'left',
  width: 100,
  sortable: true,
  search: true,
  editable: false,
  cellEdit: false,
  formatter: "date",
  formatoptions: {
    srcformat : "d/m/Y H:i:s",
    newformat: "d-M-Y"
  },
```

As for the second problem I suppose you use toolbar search and you can use this forum post in [Guriddo jqGrid Knowledgebase](http://guriddo.net/?kbe_knowledgebase=jquery-ui-datepicker-search-on-select)

Comment: Thank you very much ... the first is solved correctly , but concerning the second issue, the code is not compatible with the formatter, i.e., it's not able to understand the dash `-` present in the formatted search filter ... thus giving zero result .... so if I have a date of (28-02-2017) and I manually entered 28 , It's returned in the result, if I entered '28-' nothing is returned, If I use the date picker to select '28-02-2017' nothing is returned also

Comment: First of all you do not have allowed a search operations **like** some value. Your allowed search operations are equal, greater and etc. Second -it depend where you perform the search. If you perform the search at server you will need to refine your server search logic, when the searching is local searching and date field is not allowed with a like operations like you describe

Comment: search is local ... even after changing it to 'cn' , nothing is returned ... I think the issue is that the search is not going fine with the formatter, it seems to be searching well in the data before being foramtted, and hence not able to search in the formatted data ... do you have any idea?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid 4.5 is used exactly, so that I can check the problem correct?  There are versions from 4.5.0 to 4.5.4